# EF Core INSERT causes out of memory issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I have the following issue:

Assume I have the following objects:

```
public class Transfer
{
    public int TransferId {get; set;}
    public ICollection<ScanItem> TransferScans {get; set;}
}
public class ScanItem
{
    public int ScanItemId {get; set;}
    public TransferId {get; set;}

    public Transfer Transfer {get; set;}
}
```

**This is a simple representation of my actual Transfer class, as the Transfer class has about 11 collections on it**

I initialize the `Transfer` class, as follow:

```
var transfer = new Transfer() 
{
    TransferId = 0,
    TransferScans = new List<ScanItem>()
    {
        new ScanItem() { ScanItemId = 0, TransferId = 0 }
    }
};
```

When I call `context.Create<Transfer>(myEntity)`, I can see that the Transfer class is populated with all of the sub items (collections) populated as well.

I believe the reason that the insert is causing an `Out Of Memory error`, is becuase, each class, in each collection, contains the full `Transfer` class in the Navigation Property of each child, and each of those `Transfer` objects, also contains a full set of all collection properties again.  This, in my mind, is causing SQL to generate the SQL for each Transfer and it's collections, infinitely.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Ca you see the generated query?

Comment: What is `context.Create`? That's not a standard `DbContext` method.

Comment: @GertArnold Just a wrapper function:

public virtual void Create<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
   where TEntity : class
  {
   Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
  }

Comment: You should add that kind of info to your question, it's the first thing people will wonder. In the code you show there's nothing obviously wrong. It doesn't seem to be the real code. ("Assume I have...")

Comment: Anyways, figured it out.  When I tried to run raw SQL generated by EF Core, SQL gave me an error of not being able to convert varchar value to datetime.  Turns out, I was trying to insert empty value into a non-nullable datetime field.  The property on the model in .Net was nullable datetime, but the column in SQL was non-nullable.  Not sure why I did not get a proper message back from SQL

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify in your context definitions as:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Transfer>()
        .HasMany(e => e.TransferScans)
        .WithOne(e => e.Transfer)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.TransferId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Because in your example, one transfer contain many Items, where each Item contain a transfer, where this transfer contain again a list of items, etc , etc

If you say you have already this configuration, just try to ignore TransferId when you create a new ScaItem:

```
TransferScans = new List<ScanItem>()
{
    new ScanItem() { ScanItemId = 0 }
}
```

Comment: My mappings are setup correctly

Comment: try to ignore, TransferId (updated answer)

Comment: TransferId is an int, so whether I set it or not, it will always be 0, as it is not a nullable integer